# WinForms DataGridView does not add columns on setting DataSource

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` named `dgvInspectionsHistory`

After the following line of code runs for the first time, `dgvInspectionsHistory` adds 5 columns

```
this.ClearTable(this.dgvTemplatesConfiguration);

this.dgvTemplatesConfiguration.DataSource = templatesData;

this.dgvTemplatesConfiguration.ReadOnly = false;

//3 columns added

this.dgvTemplatesConfiguration.Columns.Add(this.CreateFaultsColumn(faultsData, "OuterFaults", 2));
this.dgvTemplatesConfiguration.Columns.Add(this.CreateFaultsColumn(faultsData, "InnerFaults", 5));

//2 more columns added

for (int i = 0; i <= dgvTemplatesConfiguration.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
     dgvTemplatesConfiguration["InnerFaults", i].Value = OkFaultName;
}
```

But after this code runs second time and indeed removes some columns, `dgvInspectionsHistory` is not getting populated back:

```
this.ClearTable(this.dgvInspectionsHistory);
this.dgvInspectionsHistory.DataSource = inspectionsData;

//the desired 3 colums are not getting added
```

Why is it so and how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: In the first code example, you use `dgvTemplatesConfiguration` and not `dgvInspectionsHistory`.

Comment: I doubt that in the first code example that any columns are added to dgvInspectionsHistory, because dgvInspectionsHistory is not referenced at all in that code. You are using another datagridview in that code. Are you sure you have put the correct code in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using two different datagrids i.e. dgvTemplatesConfiguration and dgvInspectionsHistory that's why don't have any reference try renaming dgvInspectionsHistory to dgvTemplatesConfiguration in 2nd code and check if it works